# Cannot set Longlistselector border

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a longlistselector inside a stackpanel, scrollviewer and pivot item.
The problem is no matter how I set the size of margin and borderthickness.
I couldn't get the border color visible.

This is the code I used:

```
<phone:PivotItem CacheMode="{x:Null}" Header="{Binding LocalizedResources.Settings_Appearance, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}">
    <ScrollViewer>
         <StackPanel>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding LocalizedResources.Settings_Appearance_ContentExp, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}" />
              <phone:LongListSelector Name="ContentReaderExample" Height="100" BorderThickness="5" BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}">
                   <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                             <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" FontSize="{Binding FontSize}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                   </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
              </phone:LongListSelector>
         </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</phone:PivotItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I used a border around the LongListSelector and worked fine